Почему я могу обратиться к приватному атрибуту объекта?
У меня есть следующий код:
class Door:
    def __init__(self, other=None):
        self.__room1 = None
        self.__room2 = None
        if other:
            print(other.__room1)
            self.__room1 = other.__room1
            self.__room2 = other.__room2
        print_obj_type(other or self)

other - это сторонний объект
В конструкторе класса я могу без ошибок обращаться к приватному атрибуту other.__room1. Но в следующем коде:
door_test = Door()
print(door_test.__room1)

Я вполне очевидно получу ошибку обращения к несуществующему атрибуту (из-за name mangling). Почему так работает? Почему я могу обратиться к приватному атрибуту ДРУГОГО объекта в методе класса (прошу заметить, обращаюсь не к self.__room1, а к other.__room1). Почему name mangling работает так?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Нет конкретной проблемы, мне просто интересно, почему я могу обращаться к приватному атрибуту ДРУГОГО объекта в методе класса, а в другом куске кода не могу

Это русскоязычный сайт. Переведите ваш вопрос

Перевел, было шоком распределения обычного stakoverflow и русскоязычного, думал, что дело лишь в языке интерфейса...

name mangling применяется только внутри методов классов (причём почему-то при обращении к абсолютно любым переменным, что лично мне кажется бредом, ну да ладно). Показанный вами «следующий код» door_test.__room1 не находится внутри метода класса, потому name mangling не применяется и ничего не работает, ну а other.__room1 — находится внутри метода и работает

В комментарии к вопросу andreymal дал исчерпывающий ответ.
Питон применяет name mangling внутри метода класса к ЛЮБОМУ объекту, поэтому вы можете обращаться к приватным атрибутам ЛЮБЫХ объектов в МЕТОДАХ, а в любом другом месте нет(
Надеюсь, если кто-то столкнется с такой же проблемой, то ему поможет этот ответ
